# One React app, multiple domains / subdomains

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I am researching a project for a client that needs a custom web store build. I normally work with React.js front-end and Firebase (Node.js) back-end. There is a company out there called BrightStores that allows non-coders to build and deploy web stores with a nice admin dashboard for creating many stores and products for these stores. These stores are given a subdomain by default (clientstore.myapp.com), but you can pay more for a custom domain for each store (clientstore.com). Shopify, and other service providers have similar setups. My current React.js/Firebase setup has one code base, and stores are "hosted" with React Router on separate path names ([www.myapp.com/store1](http://www.myapp.com/store1)) for each storefront. Where do I even start researching how to build a similar system of subdomains and custom domains within apps similar to Shopify and BrightStores? Any ideas on technologies for this setup?

Comment: You can build multiple sites within a single firebase project https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites

Comment: @Amin has a max of 36 sites and I don’t think this use case matches the purpose of Firebase multisites

Comment: Ah I understand your use case more now, you're right that won't work